# React app suddenly stalling (in dev and production)

Tags: reactjs

Running a react app in dev mode on localhost:3000 is stalled out with the initial loading network calls not responding.

To my knowledge, I didn't change anything between when the app was working and now.  I've tried resetting to a previous git commit during which I know the project was working but the behavior is the same.

I've tried building the project and navigating to the built project

I don't even know where to look to troubleshoot this problem.

[image: network panel with incomplete call]

Comment: That seems to be a server request which is waiting to complete. Also, it's talking about ms, it doesn't really see that bad. What are you running as a server? Without code there is nothing much to do about it in terms of giving a reasonable answer

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Icepickle that's a good one to know about.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but my project is pretty big and I can't find what part changed to make it stop working.  Even commits that used to work, when I reload them, don't any more.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Icepickle pointed out, this is fine. It's less than 1/500 of a second... it's nothing. :)

If you are still curious, you can have a look at these terms their explanations from the [Google Network Analysis Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing). Here is some related info:

> - **Queueing**. The browser queues requests when:
>
>   - There are higher priority requests.
>   - There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
>   - The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache
> - **Stalled**. The request could be stalled for any of the reasons described in **Queueing**.

Comment: Though the image indicates some number of ms for a response--you can also see that there is a notice that the response is not finished yet and, when I look at this (and the following several) network calls--there is no response at all--over many minutes.

Comment: @CaseyHill I see. It sounds like a server issue then.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the issues is associated with wrapping my app in a context from @casl/react (creating a contextual <Can> element).  It is also wrapped in a redux provider.  Are there special rules for multiple contexts?

Comment: I figured it out.  A piece of data changed and the particular context consumer had a loop that went infinite with certain data . . . stupid data.  Sorry for the bother to you but thanks for your help.